# Create an El Capitan installer on a Monterey Mac

Tags: osx-el-capitan, installation-media, macos-monterey

So, I did the dumb, I erased the HDD on an '09 iMac (El Capitan) without verifying that the third-party-created thumbdrive installer (DiskCreatorX) actually worked as a bootable drive on the machine. Turns out it didn't, and then I ruined it anyway by trying to change the partition size/filesystem type from 64 GB OS X Journaled to ExFAT 12 GB (I'm not sure why on earth I thought that would work and not erase the partition.. duh).

Now I have an '09 iMac (iPaperweight) with no OS, and it won't let me download OS X from the App Store through recovery because apparently that's no longer available (?).

But.... I have a brand new iMac running MacOS Monterey.

So... How do I create an OS X El Capitan installation media from an iMac running MacOS Monterey? The new iMac won't run the El-Cap installer package inside the `.dmg` because of machine incompatibility. I'm sure there has to be some little-documented way of actually accomplishing this... (also feel free to throw a virtual tomato at me for being dumb.)

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/379603/how-do-i-create-el-capitan-installer-on-a-catalina-or-post-el-capitan-installe and https://support.apple.com/en-gb/HT211683 [You should be able to get an 09 to boot from USB. 08/09 was about the break-point, earlier Macs had to use CD/DVD]

Comment: I gave up and bought an El Capitan disc off of eBay.  Done.